# What should you do with answers that you no longer agree with?

Tags: discussion

As one's education advances, one may find that answers that one has provided in the past which have been upvoted and perhaps even accepted are no longer consistent with one's latest understanding of the problem.  In fact, one might even consider them incorrect.

What should one do in this situation?  Provide another answer and explain the differences? Edit the existing answer?

Comment: This is an excellent question! I look forward to seeing what people think!

Comment: I'm [looking for an official answer to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290077/is-there-a-general-rule-for-what-to-do-with-your-answer-if-you-disagree-with-it) as well. Let's see what the community thinks. (cc @Sue)

Comment: @J.Musser Thanks for the SE meta post Frank!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I didn't find a rule about this situation, so when it will happen to me I will edit my first answer with a line that more or less says that I consider it obsolete and that I will write another one. This way I can be sure that my second answer gets a chance to be read, since otherwise people might read only the most upvoted answers.

I guess it would be easier for me to edit or update the first answer with all the new information, but I might feel unconfortable as this would not reflect the votes already casted. It may be that I worry too much :)

Comment: Sounds a good approach .. unless you're embarrassed about your previous answer.

Comment: I think a clearly marked edit is sufficient to one's post to demarcate a change in belief/knowledge and is both understandable and acceptable. No need to delete the first as it might prove worthy and coincide with the train of thought of the person viewing. It would be beneficial to mark the post as "Edit" before the first comment.

Comment: It's only human and unavoidable to feel a bit of embarassement about not knowing things that now seem obvious. I wouldn't worry about it since I believe everybody undarstands that we can't be all-knowing and no-mistaking from the beginning.

Comment: @Brenn You approach is logical and less time consuming, maybe you should write it as an answer because it really deserves to stand and be upvoted.